# unable to post via graph api

Tags: php, facebook

I cannot understand what is the problem in my code. I have 'publish_stream' in my scope. The user has authenticated my app with all the permissions, but still this error shows up.

The folllowing is my code to post via the graph api :-

```
<?php
    try{
        $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
            'message'       => 'TESTING...',
            'link'          => 'http://example.com',
            'picture'       => 'http://example.com/image.png',
            'name'          => 'example name!',
            'caption'       => 'example caption',
            'description'       => 'PHP SDK ROCKS!',
            ));
echo "IN TRY BLOCK ";
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
echo "IN CATCH BLOCK ";
    }

?>
```

The output for the given code is :- IN CATCH BLOCK. Please tell me where am I wrong...

Comment: as @user1909426 mentions ([in a deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15953399/558021)), you should take a look at the contents of the error object - there will probably be some useful info in there. `$e->getMessage()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Facebook Graph API documentation: 1) Check $user variable so that surely contains the (clean) Profile_ID, 2) You need to have "publish permission" on the targeted profile, see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/#publishing-permissions